# Version naming for source code with multiple build targets

Tags: java, versioning, release-management, semantic-versioning

I have a Java library which is deployed automatically to Maven central. Right now this library has Java-1.8 target SDK, I want to continue releasing source code with this target and add new target Java-17 with Java module support. Source code will be compatible with Java-1.8 versions, so both releases will be built from single source, but these releases will have different target SDK (different byte-code).

How to correctly name these artifacts for Maven central to say that it's different targets of one source code? Does some best practices exist for this? Now I'm using semver for versions, so I'm thinking about something like `<major>-<minor>-<patch>+java8` and `<major>-<minor>-<patch>+java17`, e.g. `1.3.8+java8`. I want to give a meaningful name to make it clear for users what versions they are using.

Answer (score 2):

According to the SemVer rules, versions `1.3.8+java8` and `1.3.8+java17` must compare as being the same version.

This means that if someone specifies they depend on version 1.x.x or 1.3.x of your library, two things can happen and neither is desirable.

- The dependency management tool notices two identical versions that can satisfy the dependency and gives an error, or
- The dependency management tool notices two identical versions that can satisfy the dependency and chooses one at random.

If you are producing different artifacts that target different Java versions, I would encode that as a suffix in the library name, so that your users are forced to specify which Java version they want, without having to pin the exact version of your library. That would result in the artifacts `<my_library>-java8` and `<my_library>-java17`.